# Using android-midi-lib for reading MID files in android

Tags: android, midi

I am trying to play the notes of a mid file separately for that purpose i found a library named "android-midi-lib" ([Link](https://github.com/leffelmania/android-midi-lib)).

But I am not able to get that how to integrate it in my existing android project. Can someone please me explain how to integrate it?

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Okay it was my childish mistake. All I need to copy paste the java files.